# Is there any simple from for the sum ?(originated from inclusion exclusion principle)

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Is there a more simple form for the sum?

$\sum_{i=1}^{12}\frac{12!}{(12-i)!i!}(12-i)^{56} (-1)^{i+1}$. I get 
the sum originally from a probability problem: suppose we have 56 people, and they are born in 12 months with same uniform probability. What's the probability of having at least one person born on each month?

Comment: Is the $x$ in each exponent supposed to be $i$?

Comment: The number of outcomes in which at least one of the $56$ people is born in each month is $$\sum_{k = \color{red}{0}}^{12} (-1)^k\binom{12}{k} (12 - k)^{56}$$

Comment: @N.F.Taussig, you're right about it, good. I was calculating the complementary event.